# How to choose such self-adjoint operators here.

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, spectral-theory

I'm reading Filmore's paper [On sums of projections](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/0022123669900275?token=2D5CF7A43FC3A4B4A6B33CBAD646DDB27C76202B8A7324C47A4792640DFF1DDE5A05024F483289587AB668426CDFCF53&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20230419044320). In this paper Filmore made the following remark (on page 151, last paragraph):

> By elementary spectral theory any self-adjoint operator with spectrum is $[-2, 2]$ can be written as the sum of two self-adjoint operator each having spectrum in $[-2, 2]$ and large null space (i.e. dimension of the null space is equal to the dim of the underlying separable Hilbert space).

The version of spectral theorem I know is:

> **Spectral Theorem.** For any normal operator $A$ there is a projection valued measure $E$ on $\sigma(A)$ such that
> $$A = \int_{\sigma(A)} z dE(z)$$

If we choose $P=E([-2, 0))$ and $Q=E([0, 2))$ then $A = AP + AQ$ but $AP$ may not have large null space!

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\sigma(A)$ is a finite set then there is an eigenvalue $\lambda$ such that $\mathcal{H}_\lambda:=\dim\ker (A-\lambda I)=\infty.$ We can decompose $\mathcal{H}_\lambda=\mathcal{H}_{\lambda,1}+\mathcal{H}_{\lambda,2}$ such that $\mathcal{H}_{\lambda,1}\perp \mathcal{H}_{\lambda,2}$ and $\dim\mathcal{H}_{\lambda_1}=\dim\mathcal{H}_{\lambda_2}=\infty.$   Then $$A=AP_{\mathcal{H}_{\lambda,1}}+A(I-P_{\mathcal{H}_{\lambda,1}})$$ have large null spaces, as the first summand vanishes on $\mathcal{H}_{\lambda_2},$ while the second on $\mathcal{H}_{\lambda_1}.$

Assume $\sigma(A)$ is infinite. Then it contains
a strictly monotonic sequence sequence $\lambda_n.$ Assume $\lambda_n$ is strictly increasing. Then for $\delta_n={1\over 2}\min\{\lambda_{n+1}-\lambda_n,\lambda_n-\lambda_{n-1}\}$ the projections
$P_n:=E_{(\lambda_n-\delta_n,\lambda_n+\delta_n)}$ are nontrivial and mutually orthogonal.
Let $$P=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P_{2n}$$  Then $P$ is an  orthogonal projection commuting with $A.$ Let
$$A=AP+A(I-P)$$
Then both operators are self-adjoint, with norm less than or equal $2.$ They admit  large null spaces. Namely the first summand vanishes on the range of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P_{2n+1}$ while the second on the range of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P_{2n}.$

When the sequence $\lambda_n$ is strictly decreasing, we consider $-A,$ decompose it according to the  method described above, and multiply the decomposition by $-1.$

Comment: I have two doubts: (1). Why does $P_n =E((\lambda_n-\delta_n, \lambda_n+\delta_n))\ne 0$? Since $\lambda_n \in (\lambda_n-\delta_n, \lambda_n+\delta_n)$ then in case $\lambda_n$ is an eigenvalue then I understand.

Comment: (2). Why is $\dim P(\mathcal{H})=\dim \mathcal{H}$? $P:=\sum P_{2n}$.

Comment: $P_n\neq 0,$ because $\lambda_n\in \sigma(A).$ The range of $P$ is the orthogonal sum of the ranges of $P_{2n}.$

Comment: Is it true that for any $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$ the spectral measure $E(\{\lambda\}) \ne 0$? I thought you used this to conclude $P_n\ne 0$.

Comment: But why the sum of ranges of $P_{2n}$ has the same dim as $\mathcal{H}$? Here $\lambda_n$'s are any increasing sequence it could be, say, inside $[-1, 1]$.

Comment: It does not matter where the sequence is located. The point is each $P_{2n}$ is nontrivial, they are pairwise orthogonal. So the sum has infinite dimension

Comment: If $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$ then $E(\lambda)-\delta, \lambda +\delta)$ is nontrivial.
 $E(\{\lambda\})$ may be trivial

Comment: Okay I see. $(\lambda-\delta, \lambda+ \delta)$ is nontrivial open set intersecting $\sigma(A)$. Thanks. The Hilbert space has countable dimensions so a sum of infinitely many orthogonal projections must have (countable) infinite dimension. Thank you so much .